# Can Ubuntu server connect to a WPA2 encrypted wireless network?

Tags: wireless, server, networking

I'm planning to maybe install Ubuntu server on an old machine. But my question is: can I install Ubuntu server on a machine and have it connect to my home network - wirelessly? I can't use a cable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a GUI interface to Ubuntu server to get Network Manager or following the wpa_supplicant on this page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WPAHowTo).

Comment: Does that wpa_supplicant require a graphical interface too?

Comment: wpa_supplicant can be configured from the command line.

Comment: NetworkManager can work without a GUI too...

Answer (score 5):

Note: First off you will want to make sure that the server has wpa_supplicant installed. Servers don't always have it and that can make it difficult if you can't connect it to Ethernet at least once.

This is how I do it. (be sure to use your ip numbers and network interface name)

Wont need this part for a server it is just if you wanted to kill off everything that would be interfering on a desktop.

```
sudo stop network-manager
sudo killall wpa_supplicant #must stop network-manager before this as it resurrects it.
sudo killall nm-applet
```

this only needs to be done once unless the file gets trashed. (you can put the config anywhere really)

```
wpa_passphrase "YOUR_ESSID" | sudo tee /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf #and type your password
```

`-B` for background `-s` to log to syslog `-c` to tell it where the config is. `-i` interface

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -s -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
```

for DHCP just use

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

for static ip

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.12 #Be sure to set you ip to what works for you.
```

should be able to ping your router by ip. $ ping 192.168.1.1

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 # use the ip of you router
```

should be able to ping the net at large. $ ping 8.8.8.8

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

should be done. $ ping google.com

This will not last through a reboot. To make this persist through a reboot,

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add this to the bottom (substitute for wlan0 if you have a different interface):

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

Note that you might not have the KILLALL component installed if you have a minimal  server. You can get killall with:

```
aptitude install psmisc
```

Comment: Above answer is near-perfect, although I had to add a "-i wlan0" to the pre-up line which calls wpa_supplicant. (This matches the example given further up the answer.)