# Minimalist install of Ubuntu (no applications)

Tags: customization, custom-distributions, custom-installer

Is it possible to install Ubuntu (my preferred flavour is Lubuntu) without installing all the default applications? I would only need the window manager and the settings-related programs needed to tweak the OS environment. 
I will manually install by myself any programs I may need.
Is this possible?

If not, is there any quick way to automatically uninstall all the default applications?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add applications and GUI to the minimal Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142168/how-to-add-applications-and-gui-to-the-minimal-ubuntu)

Comment: You'll want to use the NetworkInstall image (mini.iso) to install Ubuntu. Then  `sudo apt update && sudo apt install lubuntu-core` and/or choose your own packages. You can download the network installer ISO here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to construct a (sort of) minimal Ubuntu installation with i3 as my window manager. My current version of this project may be found at:

[Automate setup for Ubuntu with i3wm: (mstaal/i3buntu)](https://github.com/mstaal/i3buntu)

Even if the project itself is not of complete interest to you, the method behind constructing the setup may be. What I basically trying to do is to first install what is usually called [Ubuntu Minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) (or Ubuntu NetBoot) which is a stripped down version of Ubuntu that comes only with a minimum of packages and software and which is intended for people who want to install typical Ubuntu desktops over the internet or for people who want to make very custom Ubuntu installations.

When Ubuntu Minimal is installed, I use a [shell script](https://github.com/mstaal/i3buntu/blob/master/install.sh) to install all packages that I believe are necessary to make the Ubuntu setup that I find to be necessary to achieve a nice experience. However, I may still be needing to add *and* remove certain packages in order to get a proper and well working minimal installation. Personally, I want a setup that includes easy support for drivers, printers, Bluetooth, network and power management and other typical system utilities. It should come loaded with as little bloat as possible, however, it should be as easy as possible to install most typical software (including what I may personally consider bloat).

The thing is, that I really quite like the core idea behind the i3 window manager and the ease of Ubuntu combined with Ubuntu's huge package selection and community. I just don't want unnecessary software that takes up space and system resources.

**So all in all:** I do not know if my strategy is of any interest to you. But I have found much fun in making this script which automates my installation setup.

**By the way:** People are highly encouraged to provide feedback for my project if they have any suggestions.

Comment: Rather than down voting the suggestion one could also simply tell me why this is not of interest to the user. In that case I will of course just remove the suggestion.

Comment: Didn't downote, just edited the answer, but anyhow here is some feedback. It would be a good idea IMO if you uploaded a new file to your GitHub repository called desktop.jpg which shows what the i3buntu desktop with wallpaper.jpg as the wallpaper after it is installed. To be precise, I am thinking about a screenshot that shows the applications menu like [this Xubuntu 16.04 screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OS7Vp.png). And maybe add a link to the i3buntu desktop screenshot to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @karel! It is much appreciated. I will do that as soon as possible. Right now my internet connection is a little poor, so it may take some time.

Comment: Didn't down vote either, but I wonder if the person who did thought it looked like a "Me too" answer.  Might not have read it thoroughly.  It might not be a bad idea to start your answer with something more like "The way I am going about this in my attempt to..."

Comment: @anonymous2 The i3buntu project is on GitHub and many projects on GitHub get updated more frequently than software from repositories or PPAs, so even the "the way I am going about this..." is relevant in this case.