# Start ubuntu with minimaly necessary programs and system processes for Mixxx

Tags: startup, configuration, mixxx

I'm DJing at salsa parties using Mixxx on the laptop with ubuntu. My laptop is not very powerful and during the party some glitches happened.

My question is how to configure the ubuntu startup to run only the programs and processes necessary to smoothly execute the Mixxx djing program.

Comment: If it's an option, I would recommend you think of this in the opposite way. Instead of removing unnecessary programs, I'd recommend a minimal installation of Ubuntu, and then adding the programs you would need. I'd suggest starting with the following question if you don't mind going through that route: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142168/how-to-add-applications-and-gui-to-the-minimal-ubuntu (note: you would need to have a bit of command line knowledge to get started)

Comment: Dan is correct but if you don't have command line knowledge or don't want to get too deep you can try Different flavours of ubuntu made especially for computers with less than stellar hardware  http://lubuntu.me/ and https://xubuntu.org/  are both official Ubuntu flavours and are supported on Ask Ubuntu, it's worth taking a look